# How to make custom Image Button be responsive in Relative Layout

Tags: java, android

I'm using a `Relative-Layout` with 5 custom `Image-Button`, but when I'm running the app in different devices all the buttons become re-positioned. So can anyone tell me that if there is any way to make the buttons that supports multiple screen size.

Thank You.

Comment: Show us what you got so far.

Comment: Include your code, screenshots and layoutfile. This will help you get a quicker response. Also, follow the How To Ask guide before posting a question here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask If your question does not fit into the How To Ask guideline, you can try beginner programming forums and groups which will help you better than SO. If you've got precise technical problems with your code then post it on SO. If you do not follow the SO questions guideline your question might be downvoted or closed with no gain or response. You can edit your question and improve it, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You Should try this

An Android SDK that provides a new size unit - sdp (scalable dp). This size unit scales with the screen size. It can help Android developers with supporting multiple screens.

add implementation `'com.intuit.sdp:sdp-android:1.0.6'` to your build.gradle dependencies block.

```
 implementation 'com.intuit.sdp:sdp-android:1.0.6'
```

For The Text Kindly Use Ssp
you can find out both dependency on official site [sdp](https://github.com/intuit/sdp) for dp dimensions and [ssp](https://github.com/intuit/ssp) for sp dimensions.

**How to use the library and follow a standard?**

We have already available design standard for our designer that all designer designs PSD in xxxhdpi(1440*2560 px) resolution with a base ratio of 72ppi/dpi. From now we have to implement our XML design in either Nexus 5 (1080*1920, xxhdpi) or pixel (1080*1920, xxhdpi) device. Both devices are available in design preview in the android studio. So when we start designing we have to choose any of device from preview and design in that particular preview device, make sure that never change the device preview in the same project. i.e. if you starting your designing at the first day in nexus 5 or pixel (you can change both devices any time) then on the second day you can't change device preview from nexus 5 to nexus 4 or nexus 6P or any other. In short, we have to only design in either nexus 5 or in a pixel with given resolution as above.

Now come to the main point, when a designer gives us textsize as 70px then we have to divide given px by 4.75, i.e. 70/4.75 = 14.73 so we have to assign 15ssp size to our `TextView`. Note that we have to put ssp instead of sp and same for images we have to put sdp instead of dp as per library dimensions. Note that we have to take round off digit, i.e. 70/4.75 = 14.73 then take 15sdp, 72/4.75 = 15.15 then take 15sdp, 64/4.75 = 13.47 then take 13sdp, 107/4.75 = 22.52631 then take only 22sdp, not 21 sdp, means of you find decimal place less or equal (<=) to 5 then take the number before decimal place and if you find decimal number grater to 5 then add 1 to number before decimal place. Like in 20.15,20.25,20.45,20.55 we have to take 20sdp but in 20.65,20.75,20.95 then we have to take 21sdp.
So we have to apply the same formula at all places where designer give us some px size, like in text, images, layouts, margin, padding and any view type.

I Hope it Would Be Helpful. :)

Comment: Thanks it was really helpful. I just want to know is there any other way to scale the dpi according to devices without using any external plugins.

Comment: Umm, Will check for it, but this is the most simplest way to do try it :)